# Pass variables to another page PHP

Tags: php, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass 2 variables to another page and 1 var is required. I don't know why my code is not working properly. Take a look pls.

**Prova1.php :**

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <?php
         echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
         $nameErr="";
         $name="";

     $url="Prova1.php";

        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    if (empty($_POST["name"])){
        $nameErr = "Name is Required";
    }else{
    $url="active.php";
         }
   }  
     ?> 
      <form method="post" action="<?php echo $url ?>" >
      Name: <input type="text" name="name"/>* <?php echo $nameErr;?>
     </br>
       Email: <input type="text" name="email"/></br>
       <input type="submit"/>
      </form>

     </body>
     </html>
```

**active.php :**

```
       <html>
       <body>

           Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?> </br>
           Your email is <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: I think user has to submit twice for your code to work properly

Comment: whats the output of active.php?

Comment: Also then if you first submit with name, and second with no name it would go to active.php

Comment: the variables are name and email.  @Joni Salmi yes I noticed that but why so?

Comment: When you submit with name, it sets `$url` to `active.php` and redraws the form. Then when the user submits the form again, it goes to `active.php`, even if name isn't filled in this time.

Comment: Instead of redrawing the form, you should use a redirect.

Comment: Well first time user enter the page it sets form action to itself. Then if user submits with name the form action will change to active.php. Now because it changes the form action url only user would have to send the form one more time to be redirected to active.php. Now that active.php itself doesn't have any validation, second time submit could be empty, cause the action url is already set to active.php

Comment: @barmar no redirect. POST variables won't move with location header

Comment: mmhhh... how should You suggest me to fix it?

Comment: I know, he also has to use session variables, I'm working on a full answer.

Comment: @Barmar no I don't need a full answer I just want for now to learn the logic here. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your logic, I think your code should be something like this:

#### prova1.php

```
<html>
    <style>
        .error {color: #FF0000;}
    </style>
    <body>
        <?php

        echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
        $nameErr = "";
        $name = "";

        $url = "active.php";

        if(isset($_GET['error'])){
          if($_GET['error'] == 1){ //code for name error
            $nameErr = "name is required";
          }
        }

        ?> 
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $url ?>" >
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"/>* <?php echo $nameErr; ?>
            </br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email"/></br>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

#### active.php

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        header("Location: prova1.php?error=1");
    }
}else{
    header("Location: prova1.php");
}
?>
<html>
    <body>
        Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?> </br>
        Your email is <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry my mistake. First time I haven't copied your full code. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When the user fills in the required information, you should use a redirect, not another form, to go to `active.php`. You can pass variables using a session.

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']) {
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
    header("Location: active.php");
} else {
    $nameErr = '';
    if (isset($_INPUT['submit'])) {
        $nameErr = 'Name is required'];
    }
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="" >
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" required/>* <?php echo $nameErr;?>
        </br>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email"/></br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: it says error on variables when I press submit and I'm on active.php

Comment: You need to change active.php to use the session variables, not the post variables.

Answer (score 0):

**proval.php**

```
if(!isset($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['name'])){
  include 'form.php';
}else{
  include 'active.php';
}
```

**form.php**

```
<html>
<body><?php
     echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
     $nameErr="";
     $name="";
     if (isset($_POST["name"])){
       $nameErr = "Name is Required";
     }
 ?> 
  <form method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name"/>* <?php echo $nameErr;?>
 </br>
   Email: <input type="text" name="email"/></br>
   <input type="submit"/>
  </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

**active.php**

```
   <html>
   <body>
       Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?> </br>
       Your email is <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: when I submit nothing happens

Comment: Are you accessing proval.php. If you submit do you get Name is required error ?

Comment: you are right I was accessing form.php instead of proval.php. Now is working